# What's the right way to declare maximumdepth for the globaltoc using sphinx-bootstrap-theme?

Tags: python-sphinx, bootstrap-themes

I´m trying to run sphinx-bootstrap-theme from Ryan Romer and anything goes on the right way, but the globaltoc maximumdepth; I could not fix that in a value differente than one.

from conf.py

```
'globaltoc_depth': "3",

'globaltoc_includehidden': "true",
```

---

from theme.config

```
globaltoc_includehidden = true

navbar_fixed_top = false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not place quote marks around integers. Doing so casts them to strings. See the [theme-options for readme for sphinx-bootstrap-theme](https://github.com/ryan-roemer/sphinx-bootstrap-theme#theme-options).

The correct values in `conf.py` should be:

```
"globaltoc_depth": 3,
"globaltoc_includehidden": "true",
```

Strangely the same does not hold for booleans in the configuration.  If you don't get what you want, try changing to:

```
"globaltoc_includehidden": True,
```

Comment: This is one of the options I tried, but it didn't work and it still doesn't work a few hours later. But thanks.

Comment: Did you do a `make clean` to remove cached files? Check the build file's timestamp to ensure it is after your last run.

Comment: @StevePiercy I guess setting "true" works correctly, because it is a String. In Python, if you do a Boolean comparison with a String which is not empty (""), results in `True`.